# What is the name of the GUI Android uses/has used?

Tags: graphics

Like the GUI controlling home screen and app icons, etc.

How or what is this called that renders this?

Comment: Are you dealing with Android as it is found in Nexus phones or Android in a random Android phone, not especially a Nexus ?

Comment: If you're looking for the general term, it's **launcher**.

Comment: [How to quickly understand the Android UI](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131343/how-to-quickly-understand-the-android-ui) // [What is the analogy of the X Server on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231984/what-is-the-analogy-of-the-x-server-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

It gets the name of the Android OEM front end interface :

- *Touchwiz* for Samsung
- *HTC Sense* for HTC
- *MotoBlur* for Motorola
- ...

For the "basic" version of Android - i.e. the version embedded in Nexus phones and tablets - people often refer to the Android version as "*stock Android*". So what about "*stock Android UI*" or "*stock UI*" in this case ?

Comment: another term for stock Android could be vanilla Android.

Comment: ...and, accordingly, *Vanilla Launcher* or *Vanilla GUI*. If I remember correctly, the current one is *Trebuchet*?

Comment: @Izzy - No, Trebuchet is the launcher made by the Cyanogenmod team.  As far as I can discern, the basic vanilla android launcher from Google doesn't have an actual name.

Comment: Oh -- OK, but that's almost AOSP #D Thanks for clarification, Compro01!

Comment: The app that runs the vanilla launcher on a 4.2.2 Nexus device is called "Launcher" in the Apps list, its package name is `com.android.launcher` and it comes from an APK source of `/system/app/Launcher2.apk`. So given all that, I'm pretty sure that it's called "Launcher"