# How to quickly understand the Android UI

Tags: linux, user-interface

I have experience with Windows, the MacOS, the iPad and Linux UI's like KDE. I have not used an Android device however so I do not really understand how it works and compares. My general understanding is that it is similar to Gnome-like Linux interfaces, but I guess there must be some differences since Android has a layer of Java, [the Dalvik/ART virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime), between the Linux kernel and the UI elements.

I have read the Android [developer overview to the UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html) but that has not really helped me understand how the UI operates from a workflow basis.

Obviously I could just buy an Android tablet and use it for a few months, but I am hoping there is some way for me to understand the Android UI and how it differs from other major UIs. How can I get this knowledge?

Answer (score 5):

On **Linux** OSes kernel starts `init` which starts `getty` which starts [`login`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html) process on virtual console(s). There a user can login on CLI and a shell (like `bash`) is opened for command execution. In [windowing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system), `init` starts a [Display Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) like Xorg or Wayland and `login` is replaced with a graphical [Display Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager) like SDDM or GDM which asks for user credential on GUI. After authentication a Desktop Environment e.g. KDE or GNOME is started which starts its [Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) and shows components like Desktop, Task Bar / Panel, Widgets, Notifications, and windows of applications such as a File Explorer, Web Browser, Terminal Emulator etc.

**Android** is primarily designed for a single user, so there's no concept of CLI login. In fact virtual terminals/consoles are disabled in kernel by default. `init` - after starting all native services including Surface Flinger (Android's Display Server) - starts a service named `zygote` which is a special process to fork Java-like Virtual Machines. Android's core framework (`system_server`) and all apps run in separate instances of VMs. `system_server` starts apps which are configured to run on boot, including many system apps.

So what we see after the boot animation ends is **System UI** app. This app is responsible for showing lock screen, status bar, notifications etc. `system_server` has 100+ Java services running inside it including Activity Manager, Permissions Manager and Window Manager. WM communicates with Surface Flinger to draw surfaces on screen as requested by `system_server` and apps. Another core component we see is a **Home** or **Launcher** app which is somewhat like a Desktop. It shows, at least, icons of all installed apps and forwards the request to `system_server` for launching/showing the app when we tap an app icon. So everything we see on an Android device is an app.

Answer (score 1):

Only by using Android device.

If you don't want to buy a tablet or phone, just install Android emulator like Genymotion, Bluestacks or a classic emulator from Android SDK, but none of these would give you the great experience as using and playing with real device.

You can also watch many tutorials like
[Android Development for Beginners](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837)
which provides you a some useful information, but no direct experience

I'm saying this not only as a Android fan, but also as experienced Android Developer