# Non-root user in rooted Android phone?

Tags: root-access, lineageos, 9.0-pie, magisk, device-administrator

In my Arch Linux setup(and most others), the default user is non-root. Any admin work needs access to root account which is given temporarily with a password(generally using programs like sudo and doas).

I have recently rooted an Android phone(Redmi 4X "santoni") and installed LineageOS (android 9 version). I have TWRP, Magisk installed.

I want to setup an account which is non-admin, ie: no app can ever request superuser access and the Magisk Manager App,TWRP app will not even be visible to the user. How do I go about it?

In LineageOS' system settings there is an option called multiple users. However when I have used the "guest account" there, it still seems to have root access, ie:apps can request superuser access and Magisk is accessible too.

I looked around online but didn't find anything substantial which catered to my specific question.

Comment: Would it not be sufficient if the root-management app would require a user entered password to grant an app superuser access? That would be equivalent to a user account on the sudoers group but without the knowledge of the password. There are root management apps that have such a password protection: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/require-password-on-superuser-request.3711966/ IMHO the main problem is that Android was designed to be a completely "root-less" system from app perspective. The current way using su is a hack that was never planned for Android.

Comment: The concepts of users and how `su`, `sudo` work on normal Linuxes and Android is entirely different. I recommend you read my answers to these questions for a general understanding: [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526) and [Why are superuser permissions needed to acess /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218572/218526) and [How to quickly understand the Android UI](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221825/218526).

Comment: you can set up magisk superuser to silently deny every request