# Frame buffer not working in Android emulator when accessed from Linux

Tags: linux, android-emulator

I am running Linux with kernel from Android SDK in an Android emulator.  When writing from `/dev/urandom` to `/dev/fb0`, nothing is drawn in the emulator window.

Why?  Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Possibly related [Why is the FrameBuffer missing on some Android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232608/3573)

Comment: No, /dev/fb0 present, and
fbset -s -fb /dev/fb0

mode "720x1280"
    geometry 720 1280 720 1280 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/0,8/8,8/16,0/0
endmode

Comment: Found your [earlier SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73509845/295004) for context for any reader. As you seem to be running a HAXM QEMU, I wonder if a ARM QEMU has the same issue.

Comment: Yes, same problem with aarch64 qemu.

Comment: I can give ssh access to qemu's configuration with x11 forwarding.

Comment: Now I can't try it on a real device because I'm having trouble unlocking the bootloader.  In any case, the android emulator does not behave as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following way to run the emulator:

```
emulator -avd TINYSYS -shell -qemu -usb -device usb-tablet -device virtio-vga,edid=on,xres=720,yres=1280 -kernel /home/root/emulator/rootfs/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.302 -tiny \\
-append 'selinux=0 no_timer_check clocksource=pit no-kvmclock console=0 cma=272M@0-4G mac80211_hwsim.radios=2 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/sbin/init root=/dev/vdf2 .. .
```

/dev/vdf is the sdcard

Kernel rebuilt with virtio DRM support.